# Не могу добавить бота в игру крестики-нолики на python. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, как это работает

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь написать игру в крестики-нолики, но при попытке добавить компьютерного бота, он не может адекватно работать, поскольку игрок просто заменяет своей позицией - его позицию, хотя проверка `check_position()`, казалось бы, есть. Пробовал переписывать код разными способами. Объясните, пожалуйста, что не так с моим кодом.

```
import random

def show_board(board):
    print(board[1], '|', board[2], '|', board[3])
    print(board[4], '|', board[5], '|', board[6])
    print(board[7], '|', board[8], '|', board[9])

def check_position(board, position):
    return board[position] == '_'

def enter_player(board):
    position = 0
    while position not in range(1, 10) and not check_position(board, position):
        position = int(input('Укажите позицию от 1 до 9: '))
    return position

def enter_computer(board):
    position = 0
    while position not in range(1, 10) and not check_position(board, position):
        position = random.randint(1, 10)
    return position

def set_position(board, position, mark):
    board[position] = mark

board = list('_' * 10)
while True:
    player_position = enter_player(board)
    computer_position = enter_computer(board)
    set_position(board, player_position, 'x')
    set_position(board, computer_position, 'o')
    show_board(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас это условие

```
while position not in range(1, 10) and not check_position(board, position):
```

вроде как никогда не будет выполняться и такие вещи надо делать через ИЛИ

```
while position not in range(1, 10) or check_position(board, position):
```

т.е. пока введено не от 1 до 9 ИЛИ некорректная позиция

**P.S.**

кстати у вас еще и компьютер может зацикливаться (хотя и с малой вероятностью) - т.е. вы случайно выбираете от 1 до 9 и проверяете корректность поля, если поле уже занято - еще раз делаете тоже самое

может произойти так, что постоянно случайно будет выбрасываться некорректная позиция

поэтому делается по другому (для таких небольших объёмов данных) -

1. обойдите все поля и составьте список с корректными позициями
2. случайно выберите значение из этого списка

Comment: условие все же выполняется и переписать его через or не вариант, потому что одновременно и позиция должна быть корректной и поле должно быть пустым. вторая идея мне понравилась и я попробовал переписать функцию `enter_computer()` как:
```
def get_computer_position(board):
    positions = []
    for field in board:
        if field == '_':
            positions.append(board.index(field))
    i = random.randint(1, len(positions))
    position = positions[i]
    return position
```
но это все равно не работает. я совершенно не могу понять почему

Comment: на счет `enter_computer` - используйте библиотеку по максимуму - `position = random.choice(positions)` и все :) да и `positions` можно собрать в 1 строчку - `positions = [i for i, v in enumerate(board) if v == '_']`, и кстати немного смущает, что клеток у вас 10, работаете вы с 1 под 9, а 0 никак не отмечаете; по поводу проверки позиции пользователя то у вас условие ПОКА позиция не в диапазоне И поле не корректно, а должно быть все таки чтобы срабатывало не сразу 2 условия, а только 1 из 2 или 2 из 2 - т.е. ПОКА позиция не в диапазоне ИЛИ позиция не корректна - разве не так?

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужно поставить OR в два места: для человека и для компа.
2. Нужно обрабатывать ход сразу после ввода (поменял местами 3-ю и 4-ю строки с конца)

   ```
    import random

    def show_board(board):

        print(board[1], '|', board[2], '|', board[3])

        print(board[4], '|', board[5], '|', board[6])

        print(board[7], '|', board[8], '|', board[9])


    def check_position(board, position):

        return board[position] == '_'


    def enter_player(board):

        position = 0

        while position not in range(1, 9) or not check_position(board, position):

            position = int(input('Укажите позицию от 1 до 9: '))

        return position


    def enter_computer(board):

        position = 0

        while position not in range(1, 9) or not check_position(board, position):

            position = random.randint(1, 9)

        return position


    def set_position(board, position, mark):

        board[position] = mark


    board = list('_' * 10)

    show_board(board)

    while True:

        player_position = enter_player(board)

        set_position(board, player_position, 'x')

        computer_position = enter_computer(board)

        set_position(board, computer_position, 'o')

        show_board(board)
   ```